# Problems with WP_Query, Loop, a condition and Posts per Page

Tags: wp-query, loop

I am creating a website and I have Custom Types (Plugin: [Types](https://wordpress.org/plugins/types/)). These Custom Types are called 'Veranstaltungen' --> they are Events.

All of these Events have a starting date ( `start-datum` ) and an end date ( `end-datum` ) which are Custom Fields.

On my website homepage I want to display a 3 of these Events.

I've got the loop working with my sorting order and I can limit it to 3 by using this:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array(                
    'post_type'        => 'veranstaltungen',    
    'posts_per_page'   => '3',
    'orderby'          => 'meta_key',
    'order'            => 'ASC',
    'key'              => 'start-datum',
) );
```

The Events of the Past are showing up.

The next 3 Events according to the custom field `start-datum` are the ones who shall appear.

I added this if-logic:

```
while( $link->have_posts() ) :
    $link->the_post(); 

    if( date( 'm d,Y',strtotime( "today" ) ) <= types_render_field( 'end-datum', array( 'format' => 'm d, Y' ) ) )
    {
        ...
```

This works but The Loop takes the "outdated posts" into account and screws up my `posts_per_page`.

If we think of today and I have 2 Events in the past I will just see 1 Event.

How can I fix this problem?

---

I tried to do this instead of the conditional and tried to exclude my posts in The Loop but it didn't work. It just sorts my posts and prints everything:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array(                
    'post_type'     => 'veranstaltungen',   
    'posts_per_page'=> '3',
    'orderby'       => 'meta_key',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'key'           => 'end-datum',
    'value'         =>  date( 'F j,Y',strtotime( "today" ) ),
    'compare'       => '>=',
    'type'          => 'DATE',              
) );
```

Comment: What is the format of your `*-datum` fields?

Comment: Do you mean how I display these things in the Template or in the Backend?
I use them in the Templat like this:
<?php echo types_render_field("start-datum", array('format'=>'m d, Y'));?>

Comment: No. What does the data look like in the database?

Comment: Could you tell me how I can do that?

Comment: If you add `echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'start-datum', true );` in the loop, what does the output look like?

Comment: I already tried that and it doesnt output anything.
i tried it with the Name I found in Types Settings --> Custom Type Name (wpcf-start-datum)
and it outputs me stuff like: 1446652800

Comment: I don't know how that plugin works, it would seem you need to be using the key `wpcf-start-datum` and not `start-datum`. The value looks like a timestamp, so you should be comparing the date to today's date as a timestamp, not a formatted date (which the database engine can't understand anyway). You should also look at the [`meta_query` examples](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) to see how to properly format one.

Answer (score 0):

Just for your Info. 
I switched my Plugin to Advanced Custom Fields and created the Query like this. Maybe it was because of the "-" I used in my CustomField or it was the format of my Date.

```
$today = date('Ymd');
$args=array(
   'post_type' => 'veranstaltungen',
   'posts_per_page' => 3,   
   'meta_query' => array(
        array(
       'key' =>  'ende',
       'compare' => '>=',
       'value' => $today,   
        ),      
    ),  
       'meta_key' =>  'start',
       'orderby' => 'meta_value',
       'order' => 'ASC',   
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);            
?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

Thanks to everyone trying to help! :)